# How to add two tables with PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots

I have two files `file1.dat` and `file2.dat` to generate two curves using PGFPlots (these two files share the same *x* values). I would like only to draw the curve associated to `file1.dat` and the curve whose *y* values are equal to the sum of *y* values of the `file1.dat` and of `file2.dat`.

How I can do it?

Currently, I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 axis x line=bottom,
 axis y line=left,
 xlabel={Number of elements.},
 ylabel={Errors.},
 xmin=1,
 xmax=4]
 \addplot+ [name path=A] table {file1.dat};
 \addplot+ [name path=B] table {file2.dat};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide an MWE with what you have achieved so far. Then it remains for us (the helpers) to modify your code instead of also creating some dummy data files etc.

Comment: Thanks @Raaja for adding some code, which still isn't an MWE because e.g. the preamble is missing. Also so far there are no data files.

Comment: Anyway, most likely you are asking for `stack plots=y` which should be added to the `axis` options.

Comment: @Raaja, that was no criticism to you, but to OP ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While my initial reaction was that it would be far more appropriate (and easier) to simply add the two values together using another program or script, it turns out the `pgfplotstable` package is pretty well equipped and you can do everything you want to without leaving LaTeX. You didn't provide any data, so I created dummy `file1.dat` and `file2.dat` files (using the `filecontents` package so you can see them here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% Dummy file data
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
x y
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.dat}
x y
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
% Read data from files into two tables
\pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
\pgfplotstableread{file2.dat}{\tableb}
% Define rules used to create columns in a new table
\pgfplotstableset{
     create on use/x/.style={create col/copy column from table={\tablea}{x}}, % Copy x values from first (or 2nd) table
     create on use/y1/.style={create col/copy column from table={\tablea}{y}}, % Copy y values from first table
     create on use/y2/.style={create col/copy column from table={\tableb}{y}}, % Copy y values from second table
     create on use/sum/.style={create col/expr={\thisrow{y1}+\thisrow{y2}}}     % Sum y values
}
% Create a new table with columns x,y1,y2,sum (according to above rules) 
% and with same number of rows as first (or 2nd) table)
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x,y1,y2,sum}]{\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tablea}}\tablec
% Now plot all data in the usual way
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          ymin=0, ymax=30,
          xmin=0, xmax=5,
          xlabel={$x$},
          ylabel={$y$},
          grid=major,
          legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
          legend pos = north west
          ]
        % Select appropriate columns
        \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y1] {\tablec};
        \addplot [green, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y2] {\tablec};
        \addplot [red, mark=*] table [x=x,y=sum] {\tablec};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
% Take a look at the new table so we can check things worked as expected
\pgfplotstabletypeset\tablec
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

I would definitely recommend having a look at the `pgfplotstable` documentation for more information on the different commands I've used here.